# How do I remove a server-added header from proxied location?

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx proxy setup where I add several security-related headers to the server so that they return on all proxy locations. On some locations I need to add additional headers (ex. `Content-Security-Policy` to `/`), while on other specific locations I need to remove one of the headers (ex. `X-Frame-Options` from `/framepage.html`) added at the server level.

## `nginx.conf`

```
# ...

server {
  # ...

  include security-headers.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000/;
    include security-headers.conf;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "my csp...";
  }

  location = /framepage.html {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000/framepage.html;
    # TODO: remove `X-Frame-Options` response header from this specific page
    # Tried add_header X-Frame-Options "";
    # Tried proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options "";
    # Tried proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api:5000/;
  }

  location /otherstuff/ {
    proxy_pass http://otherstuff:5000/;
  }

  # ...
}
```

## `security-headers.conf`

```
add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

I have tried the following, but none of them seem to remove the `X-Frame-Options` header from the `/framepage.html` location response:

- `add_header X-Frame-Options "";`
- `proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options "";`
- `proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;`

How can I remove the `X-Frame-Options` header from the `/framepage.html` location response?

Comment: Is your backend server sending this header, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no, it is only set by the parent server block include statement.

Answer (score 43):

The header config attributes are a bit confusing, this is what they do:

`proxy_set_header` is to set a request header 
`add_header` is to add a header to the response 
`proxy_hide_header` is to hide a response header

If you want to replace a header that already exists in the response it is not enough with `add_header` because it will stack the values (from server and the one you added).

You have to do this in two steps:

**1)** remove header:
`proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;`

**2)** add your custom header value:
`add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" always;`

Comment: help, proxy_hide_header works with proxy_pass, it doesn't work with 'return'

Comment: @datdinhquoc What do you mean with *"it doesn't work with 'return'"*? Could you elaborate or even better post a question and send me a link?

Comment: i want to change a response header, but 'return' in server block will pass the url to browser and some http 302 happen in browser, i cant add the extra header to the final redirected url

Comment: This only works for response headers set by an upstream server but not for headers set by nginx self like "server" header for example.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the headers_more module. Example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://upstream_server/;
    more_clear_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
}
```

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/

Answer (score 5):

You could probably try to use the 3rd party "Headers More" module:

https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module

And something along the lines of:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

http {
    ...
    more_clear_headers 'X-Frame-Options';
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't `include security-headers.conf` at the `server` level. Only `include` it in each individual `location` where you want these headers to be sent.

The reason for this is that [`add_header`](https://nginx.org/r/add_header) directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if the current level has no `add_header` directives. Thus, your including them in the `server` block causes them to be included in every `location` as you aren't overriding them in any `location`.

Comment: Yes, I was actually doing this intentionally since I wanted them to apply to all locations without having to include it at every location. It sounds like what I am trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Sure it is, just follow my instructions and DO NOT put it in the `server` or in the `location` where you don't want the headers sent.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Nginx Lua module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/).

You will need the `nginx-extras` package installed. For example in aptitude do a `apt install nginx-extras`.

In `nginx.conf`:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;

http {
  ...

  header_filter_by_lua_block {
    ngx.header["server"] = nil
  }
}
```

To verify run a `nginx -V` and you will see `http-lua`. The `ndk_http_module.so` is needed to load the `ngx_http_lua_module.so` module.

Always best to run an `nginx -t` to verify your configuration, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

We have global CSP rules at the nginx.conf (http) level which then needed to be removed at the server level / virtualhost level to let the proxied CSP header - generated by the app - surface (otherwise we got 2 x CSP headers and the most restrictive applies).

The below worked for me.

```
server {
  listen           443 ssl;
  server_name      foobar.domain.tld;
  ...

  # Custom CSP or Clear CSP
  # Remove default CSP from nginx.conf for this custom one. 
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "";

  location / {
      proxy_pass ...
      ...
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.